# I have to different zip files created using JSZip. Is is possible to combile them into one archive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jszip

How to combine two already created zip archive?

```
const zip1 = new JSZip();
const zip2 = new JSZip();

// const zip3 = ? - contains both zip1 and zip2
```

Comment: You can zip zip1 and zip2 into a zipall. The filesize will be mostly the size of both idividual zip files added together.

Comment: Can you explain what is zipall?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. is zipall a method of JSZip?

Comment: Maybe you can explain how to zip files into one .zip file?

Comment: Here it shows how to read a file into zip. You will need to read both files into the same zip instance. If I have some time later I'll try to write an example. https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html. See: "In node Js" the comment // read a file and add it to a zip. You need to call file twice one for each file.

Answer (score 0):

```
(async () => {
  
  const zip1 = new JSZip();
  const zip2 = new JSZip();
  ...

  let mergeZip = new JSZip();
  for (let zipObject of [zip1, zip2, ...]) {
    mergeZip = await mergeZip.loadAsync(
      await zipObject.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }),
      { createFolders: true }
    );
  }
  saveAs(await mergeZip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }), `example.zip`);
})();
```